# How to use ControlPaint.DrawGrid To Draw To a PictureBox

Tags: c#, grid, drawing, imaging

I am attempting to draw a graph paper like grid to a picture box and then printing it out.  I figured my best route of attack for this would be the DrawGrid function.  I got some stuff down and then it fell apart after I got to the control paint part.  How can I convert a Painting to drawing.  Please explain, as of now I am fairly confused.

```
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
            rect.Height = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            rect.Width = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;

            ControlPaint.DrawGrid(File(yourImage), mygrid, yourImage.Size, System.Drawing.Color.Black);

            pictureBox1.Image = //What should be here
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawgrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) : _Draws a grid of __one-pixel dots__ with the specified spacing, within the specified bounds, on the specified graphics surface, and in the specified color._

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your creating an Image from code, you need create a Bitmap of correct dimensions. Then do double loop through all pixels choosing the colors as needed.
Then set as Image for the PictureBox and/or save to file.

Answer (score 0):

I see three ways to do it:

- Here is how you can create a Bitmap with the Grid:

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
   Size yourGridspacing = new Size((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);
   using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
   {
      ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 
                               yourGridspacing , Color.Black);
   }
   // now you can save it..
   bmp.Save("yourPngFileName, ImageFormat.Png);
   // ..or insert it as the Image..      
   pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
   // ..or as the Background Image:
   pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
}
```

You should insert a line to `Dispose` the Image before setting it, if you play with different grid spacing, so you don't leak the memory! E.g.:

```
   if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
```

- Or you can instead simply put the Drawing code into the Paint event and let it be drawn on each Invalidate:

---

```
void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
   Size yourGridspacing = new Size((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);
   using (Graphics G = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
         ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 
                                  yourGridspacing , Color.Black);

}
```

Please note the meaning of the [BackColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawgrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter:

> The backColor parameter is used to calculate the fill color of the
>   dots so that the grid is always visible against the background.

This means that you can't really control the coor of the Grid. Instead the system will pick one that contrats with the `BackColor` parmeter. So if your PictureBox happens to be  `White` a param of `Black` will be invisible!!

So the best way to set that param is:

```
ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 
                         yourGridspacing , Color.Black);
```

which will always work except for `Color.Transparent`.. (in which case the Color of the control below will decide if the Grid is visible..)

- Or, if you want to, you may instead use the `BackgroundImage` as a tiny `Bitmap`  of the Size of your grid spacing, which you Tile. That will take the less memory than using a large Bitmap.:

---

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(0, 0, Color.Black);
    }
    if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    pictureBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Tile;
}
```

This will also give you full control over the actual color!

Comment: Mak sure to understand the new remarks on the right way to choose the color! (Which is a bit weird, admittedly..) - If your problem is resolved, please consider accepting the answer!