# Why Isn't ControlPaint.DrawGrid Function not Displaying Anything to a PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, grid, picturebox

I want to make a graph paper grid and set the drawing to the image of a picture box. Now I might even be using the wrong thing for drawing a graph paper grid but I have asked around and some people said that the `DrawGrid` method would work. None of the code below is returning any errors, but when I run the `button1_Click` method, it doesn't display anything to the `picturebox`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button2.Visible = true;

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
    Size yourGridspacing = new Size((int)numericUpDown1.Value, (int)numericUpDown2.Value);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
         ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), yourGridspacing , Color.Black);
    }

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: The code **should** work.  Have u checked that `yourGridspacing` is correct? Or `pictureBox1` is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PictureBox` probably has a `White`  Background.. If so, please tell the `ControlPaint.DrawGrid` method so..:

```
     ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 
                           yourGridspacing , Color.White);
```

The param **doesn't** control the **color** of the dots; it is supposed to help find a Color that will **contrast**. So maybe the best way to write it will be:

```
     ControlPaint.DrawGrid(G, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size), 
                           yourGridspacing, pictureBox1.BackColor);
```

This will work for all colors except `Color.Transparent`.. (in which case the Color of the control below will decide if the dots are visible..)

You may wonder, why such a roundabout way is chosen? Well, the method `DrawGrid` is not really meant as a normal drawing method, like the ones in `Graphics`. It is one of several methods that are meant to construct a robust display of Windows controls like `Button` or `CheckBox`.. Now, the Background over which the Grid is drawn need **not** have **only one** Color; it could be an Image or a Gradient and it could change..

You are supposed to pick a typical color to represent that background. The system will then choose a Color with good contrast for the dots.

For a way to control the grid's color see the last option in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206510/how-to-use-controlpaint-drawgrid-to-draw-to-a-picturebox/28210149?noredirect=1#comment44817076_28210149)!

Comment: Thanks all your help has greatly helped me and answered all my questions.  Have a good day or night and hopefully I will see you around again.  I would rate your questions with a thumbs up but I dont have the reputation points to do such.